# Facebook Iframe App - prompting for secure content although I have SSL installed?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ssl

Weve finally got SSL installed on our server, so that we can have users surfing our simple HTML iframe tabs.

The problem im experiencing is in IE8+IE9 and I only experience it when browsing with "Secure browsing" on. So if I visit the same page with just "http" everything works.

When I visit my iframe tab, I get prompted with a message saying something along the lines of:

"Only secure content is shown"

At this point I can see my content, but only 800px of height (it is higher).
So seems that my javascript to autoresize havent been triggered yet.

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
FB.Canvas.setSize({ width: 520, height: 1400 });

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();
}

</script>
```

But then if I decide to click the button saying "Show all content", TWICE, then it will autoresize.
Ive tried visiting other iframe tabs with "https" and dont seem to get prompted with this there.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution might be as simple as forcing the facebook JS SDK to be loaded over https.  As opposed to using a protocol relative URL.
Please see [this SO question](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8309517/facebook-and-ssl-partially-encrypted) that also talks about partially encrypted facebook pages.

Comment: Lix - you're a god. I was loading it with "http" and changing it to "https" as recommended, it it now working as supposed. Thanks!